# Toggling between screens using setVisible(boolean) in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have created a simple game in Swing which has a screen. Clicking on a cell results in color change of two adjacent cells. This is achieved by this code:

```
     public class SelfGrid extends BattleGrid {
        @Override
     protected JPanel getCell()
     {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.black);
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 1));

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));


        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()   {
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
          {  

        panel.setSize(new Dimension(20,80));
        panel.setBackground(Color.orange);
      }
    }
    });

   return panel;
      }
    }

  public abstract class Battle extends JPanel {
   public BattleGrid() {
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    JPanel grid = new JPanel();
    grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,10));
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel = getCell();

        grid.add(panel); 
        }
       }
    this.add(grid);
     }    
     protected abstract JPanel getCell();
     }
```

When I use setVisible(boolean) method to toggle between two screens and the original screen is brought back, only the cells that were clicked on remain colored. In other words, the dimension of each JPanel is restored to 20,20. I was told that this is because setVisible() method actually repaints components on the screen. How can I bring back the original screen without any changes being made to it contents? Thank you.

Comment: This is not the first time I've seen this (basic) question asked in recent days. As was told to the previous poster, without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will be impossible to provide a accurate and reliable solution to your problem

Comment: This "basic" question nobody can answer... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making programatic color changes directly to the UI elements, create a two dimensional array that represents the colors of the cells, and modify that. Then, repaint the cells based off the values in the array each time visibility changes or a cell is clicked.